# how to make an arc in span in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a half arc in CSS with different colors as shown in image.

[image]

I used the following code.

HTML

```
 <div class="gradient">
   <span class="one"></span>
   <span class="two"></span>
   <span class="three"></span>
   <span class="four"></span>
   <span class="five"></span>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.gradient span{

height: 10px;
display: block;
width: 100px;
}

.gradient .one{
  background-color: red;
}

.gradient .two{
  background-color: green;
}

.gradient .three{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.gradient .four{
  background-color: black;
}

.gradient .five{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Actully i wants to make this half gauge meter in css with rounded corner of every span.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, at least not like that image. Seems like a job for SVG.

Comment: Not able to do this svg as well. please help!

Comment: It is possible in CSS, i mean ive seen 3d worlds in raw css ... but it takes someone very unique to do it lol to get something like this made i would try paying for a dev on a free lance site like fiverr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make something similar by `conic-gradient` and `radial-gradient`, but without round corner on the color.

```css
.round {
  --start: -90deg;
  --m: 1.8deg;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(var(--start));
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, white 0%, white 66%, transparent 66%, transparent 100%),
    conic-gradient(#ff8b8b calc(0deg + var(--m)),
      #ff8b8b calc(36deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(36deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(36deg + var(--m)),
      #ffd68b calc(36deg + var(--m)),
      #ffd68b calc(72deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(72deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(72deg + var(--m)),
      #f7ff8b calc(72deg + var(--m)),
      #f7ff8b calc(108deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(108deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(108deg + var(--m)),
      #bfff8b calc(108deg + var(--m)),
      #bfff8b calc(144deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(144deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(144deg + var(--m)),
      #68ff68 calc(144deg + var(--m)),
      #68ff68 calc(180deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(180deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(360deg + var(--m))
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
```

**EDIT**

Found out that add some small dot can make it looks rounded.

```css
.round {
  --start: -90deg;
  --m: 3deg;
  --bw: 6px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(var(--start));
  background-image:
    conic-gradient(transparent var(--m),
      #ff8b8b var(--m),
      #ff8b8b calc(36deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(36deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(36deg + var(--m)),
      #ffd68b calc(36deg + var(--m)),
      #ffd68b calc(72deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(72deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(72deg + var(--m)),
      #f7ff8b calc(72deg + var(--m)),
      #f7ff8b calc(108deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(108deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(108deg + var(--m)),
      #bfff8b calc(108deg + var(--m)),
      #bfff8b calc(144deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(144deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(144deg + var(--m)),
      #68ff68 calc(144deg + var(--m)),
      #68ff68 calc(180deg - var(--m)),
      transparent calc(180deg - var(--m)),
      transparent 360deg);
}

.round::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  inset: var(--bw);
  background-color: white;
}

.round span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: rotate(var(--d));
  display: block;
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 50%;
}

.round span::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--bw);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--clr);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="round">
  <span style="--d: calc(0deg + var(--m)); --clr: #ff8b8b;"></span>
  <span style="--d: calc(36deg - var(--m)); --clr: #ff8b8b;"></span>
  <span style="--d: calc(36deg + var(--m)); --clr: #ffd68b;"></span>
  <span style="--d: calc(72deg - var(--m)); --clr: #ffd68b;"></span>
  <span style="--d: calc(72deg + var(--m)); --clr: #f7ff8b;"></span>
  <span style="--d: calc(108deg - var(--m)); --clr: #f7ff8b;"></span>
  <span style="--d: calc(108deg + var(--m)); --clr: #bfff8b;"></span>
  <span style="--d: calc(144deg - var(--m)); --clr: #bfff8b;"></span>
  <span style="--d: calc(144deg + var(--m)); --clr: #68ff68;"></span>
  <span style="--d: calc(180deg - var(--m)); --clr: #68ff68;"></span>
</div>
```